# Block or dismiss notifications based on content?

Tags: macos, notifications

On macOS, is there any way to intercept notifications or automatically dismiss specific notifications? I know that I can enable notifications on a per-application basis, but I'm looking for more fine-grained control. Some applications send me a mix of interesting and uninteresting notifications, and I'd like to filter those down so I only see the interesting ones.

- Is it possible to intercept notifications before they are shown? For example, are there any hooks that would let me register a shell script to filter notifications?
- Is it possible to automatically dismiss notifications after they are shown? Perhaps there is an AppleEvent that could trigger an AppleScript, or some other Automator-based trigger?
- Is there some other mechanism I haven't thought about that would allow me to exercise more control about which notifications get shown to me?